# Run `kubectl apply` using yaml stored in a variable

Tags: powershell, kubectl

I have a resource I want to apply as part of an automated script (running in powershell).  I would rather not have to write it out to a file then have to deal with cleaning it up.

Is it possible to apply the yaml as part of a script?

Something similar to this:

```
$myYaml = @'
apiVersion: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ServiceAccount-clusteradmin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ClusterAdmin
subjects:
  - apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind: User
    name: "MyAdminServiceAccount"
'@

kubectl apply @myYaml
```

Clearly, the `kubectl` command above does not work.

**My question is: Is a way to apply this yaml without creating a file (using powershell)?**

Comment: PowerShell has no built-in YAML support, so your options are to install a third-party module or to declare `$myYaml` as a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal instead. _Update_: But it sounds like _piping_ the YAML to the `kubectl` executable is the simplest solution, as shown in P....'s answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myYaml` is a variable having the data:

```
$myYaml = @'
apiVersion: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ServiceAccount-clusteradmin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ClusterAdmin
subjects:
  - apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind: User
    name: "MyAdminServiceAccount"
'@
```

Perform the following to echo the contents of `$myYaml` variable and pipe it to `kubectl apply -f -`, here last `-` is for piped input.

```
$myYaml |kubectl.exe apply -f -
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ServiceAccount-clusteradmin created

kubectl.exe get rolebindings
NAME                          ROLE                       AGE
ServiceAccount-clusteradmin   ClusterRole/ClusterAdmin   18s
```

This is very similar to `linux` environment where `echo "$var" |kubectl apply -f -` is used to perform same action.